# I am getting a syntax error can you please check my code?

Tags: excel, vba

Kindly check the code, I think the mistake lies in exiting the error loop.

```
Option Explicit
Dim mm
Dim person As Range
Dim amount As Range
Dim ans

Sub Macro1()

again:
mm = InputBox("Enter the name of the sales person")
If mm = "Jack" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Heather" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Jeff" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Stephanie" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Mike" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Marty" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Peter" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Jack" Then
    GoTo Start
ElseIf mm = "Lisa" Then
    GoTo Start
Else
GoTo Error
Error:
MsgBox ("Error: invalid name,no match found")
ans = MsgBox("Do you want to try again?", vbYesNo)
If ans = 8 Then
GoTo again
ElseIf ans = 7 Then
GoTo Exit

Start:
    Set person = Range(Cells(6, 2), Cells(148, 2))
    Set amount = Range(Cells(6, 3), Cells(148, 3))
    Cells(13, 8) = mm
    Cells(14, 8) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(amount, person, mm)
    Cells(15, 8) = WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(amount, person, mm)
    Cells(16, 8) = WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(amount, person, mm)
    Cells(17, 8) = WorksheetFunction.MaxIfs(amount, person, mm)
    ans = MsgBox("Do you want to try again?", vbYesNo)
If ans = 8 Then GoTo again
    End If
Exit:
End Sub
```

For some weird reason excel is not allowing me to enter Exit: it shows compile error, but i do not know why

Thank you so much for helping

Comment: `Exit` is a reserved word, you can't use it as a Label. But as already mentioned, this could use some rework. You're missing a couple instances of `End If`.

Comment: @urdearboy can you please suggest an alternate method-if i remove goto start what should i exchange it with ? i am new to vba and programming,kindly bear with me. Thankyou !

Comment: @BigBen Thanks a lot. The issue seems to have been fixed once i changed my label :) Have a great day

Comment: Now that your code works, feel free to post it on [codereview.se] to get tips on restructuring the control flow, and avoiding `GoTo` jumps.

Answer (score 3):

`Exit` is a reserved keyword, illegal for an identifier.

> ```
> Exit:
> End Sub
> ```

That `Exit` label needs to be renamed.

Comment: @NightFury we take our thank you here's by way of accepting solutions that solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would go about re-structering your code. Notice that the code is not jumping from here to there due to instances of `GoTo`. Now, you can follow the logic from start to end without skipping a line. This goes a long way with readability which helps with debugging, modifying in future, and writing your script in the first place.

You can add a `Do Loop` if you would like to present the option to keep trying at names until they happen to enter one of your action names. You should look up that method, and if you decide to implement and have any issues,  post a new question with your code and problem!

Here are a few random links on that topic that should help to get you started. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18149375/inputbox-do-until-two-letters-are-entered), or [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2015/3/26/loop-input-box-until-receives-correct-valid-entry)

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update sheet name
Dim mm As String, Person As Range, Amount As Range

Set Person = ws.Range("B6:B148")
Set Amount = ws.Range("C6:C148")

mm = InputBox("Enter the name of the sales person")

Select Case mm
    Case "Jack", "Heather", "Jeff", "Mike", "Marty", "Peter", "Jack", "Lisa"
        ws.Range("H13") = mm
        ws.Range("H14") = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Amount, Person, mm)
        ws.Range("H15") = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Amount, Person, mm)
        ws.Range("H16") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Minifs(Amount, Person, mm)
        ws.Range("H17") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Maxifs(Amount, Person, mm)
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry. Please re-run macro to try again"

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Aaaah, this is what I hate about upvoting too early.... can't upvote again post-edit!